# lights out game, with switching images possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just had an idea that the old "lights out" game could make a nice little image gallery/game.

It would be something simple like a 5 x 5 grid of images,

```
☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐
☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐
☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐
☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐
☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐
```

a number of the images could be shown/visible why the others are hidden.

Like the old 'lights out' game when you click a box/image it will turn on or off (show or hide) depending on that box/images current state and the boxes/images directly above, below, left and right also.

This is just a fun little experiment and doesn't need to be randomised each time like the proper game I'm happy to just enable and disable images manually at the start each time. I only have html5/css3 knowledge and I'm not really that good at JQuery.

Is this possible and does anyone know how?

This is my basic template I was going to use:
http://jsfiddle.net/rd4k24L2/1/

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
section#imagegame {width:1000px}
section#imagegame .imageblock {width:194px; height:194px; margin:2px; float:left; border:1px solid grey;}
section#imagegame .imageblock img {display:none; width:100%; height:auto;}
img.initiallyshow {display:block !important; width:100%; height:auto;}
</style>

<section id="imagegame">
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">

        <img id="a1" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />

    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="a2" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="a3" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="a4" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="a5" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>

<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b1" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b2" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b3" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b4" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b5" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>

<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="c1" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <a href="">
        <img id="c2" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="c3" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="c4" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="c5" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>

<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d1" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d2" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d3" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d4" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d5" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>

<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e1" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e2" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e3" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e4" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>
<a href=""> 
    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e5" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>
</a>    

</section>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add your relevant code (HTML, JavaScript and CSS) in your question; don't just link it and expect us to follow. And, as it stands, your 'question' reads like you're asking us to provide you with the JavaScript to make this game work. Instead, reduce your example down to a minimal case and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible, but I haven't given much thought as to how. Apparently neither have you. Could you update the question showing what problems you're getting with the js

Comment: I've added the code, its basically the layout of my idea and how I think it would work. I didn't mean it to sound like a someone do this for me, as I said I'm still quiet new, I had an idea and don't know whats involved, or even whether Javascript was what I needed exactly. I just wanted help with being put in the right direction with maybe something to follow to make this happen. I'm trying to learn but don't have the knowlege others have and thats why I post here.

Comment: I have given each image a unique id A1-5, B1-5, C1-5, D1-5, E1-5. So if you click B2 it switches B2, B1, B3, A2 & C2 to the opposite display state they currently are. If I could could maybe figure out how to do this I could apply it to the rest of the grid. Thats how I think it would work but I could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the html to get the anchor tags out because they are messing with jQuery click function.

There you are:

```
<div id="wehaveawinner" style="display:none">YOU WON!</div>
<section id="imagegame">

    <div class="imageblock">

        <img id="a1" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />

    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="a2" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="a3" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="a4" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="a5" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b1" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b2" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b3" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b4" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="b5" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="c1" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">

        <img id="c2" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="c3" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="c4" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="c5" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>


    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d1" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>


    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d2" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d3" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d4" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="d5" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e1" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e2" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e3" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e4" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="imageblock">
        <img id="e5" class="initiallyshow" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs13/f/2007/040/b/7/Photo__Large_red_square_by_TheLastDanishPastry.png" />
    </div>

</section>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$('.imageblock').click(function() {
    var img = $(this).children("img");
    img.toggleClass("initiallyshow");
    var id = img.attr('id');
    var l = id.substring(0,1);
    var ln = l.charCodeAt(0);
    var d = parseInt(id.substring(1));

    if(d>1) $('#'+l+(d-1)).toggleClass("initiallyshow");
    if(d<5) $('#'+l+(d+1)).toggleClass("initiallyshow");
    if(ln>("a".charCodeAt(0)))
        $('#'+String.fromCharCode(ln-1) + d).toggleClass("initiallyshow");
    if(ln<("e".charCodeAt(0)))
        $('#'+String.fromCharCode(ln+1) + d).toggleClass("initiallyshow");

    if( $('.initiallyshow').length == 0 )
        $('#wehaveawinner').show();
    else
        $('#wehaveawinner').hide();

    return false;
});
```

This is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rd4k24L2/14/

The idea is that toggling the class is extremely simply with jQuery but given the html structure you prepared, it's a little tricky to get the right squares to toggle.

If you had prepared a different structure, the js code could have been reduced to a very few lines.

Edit: 
A version with a very simple win detection: http://jsfiddle.net/rd4k24L2/16/

Comment: There is a problem with Chrome and the string functions, I will see what the deal is and correct the code accordingly. It works flawlessly in Firefox.

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks, now I just need to figure out how to affect the blocks above,below, left & right of the clicked block too. So as mentioned I've gen each image a unique ID if you click B2 it switches B2, B1, B3, A2 & C2 to the opposite display state they currently are. Sorry about the structure I created it the way I thought it would work, what would you recommend to improving the structure?

Comment: Corrected for Chrome. My code should modify all the required blocks. Try the new jsFiddle.

Comment: Ah I see, I was testing it in chrome, you've actually got it working as i described above, thats crazy in such a few lines of code, I'm going to study the script and work out how it functions, thank you :)

Comment: Your amazing, Thank you, this has helped massively :D

Comment: If you wanted to have a simple function, your structure should make easy to get from a cell to the nearby cells. That can be accomplished, for example, by having the ids with a sequential numerical part (for example from 'c1' to 'c25'), so that to get the one above I just have to add 5 or subtract 5. Obviously there are many other ways to do that.

Comment: ah right so instead of ID's of 'A1'-'A5' then 'B1'-'B5' etc to indicate rows I should have just made them all 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' etc all the way up to 'A25' would have made it easier? I have one final question is there a way of adding a message if all images are visible? (or initiallyshow are all toggled on?) would be nice to just add a div above that is hidden but would display the message if all are visible. I understand you've done a lot already and I'm more than happy, it was just an after thought if not.

Comment: Added a very simple win detection :)